# JQuery - random code generator on selecting data in select options without if condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing the code for generating random code using jQuery. It was working fine. But I used if condition to achieve that. What I need is to write that function **without** if conditions... how can I get that ?

```js
 function getcodes()
    {
      
      var input_data  = $('.getvalue').val();
      var select_data = $('.control').val();
      if(select_data == "Binary" )
      {
        select_data = "BY";
      }
      else if(select_data == "Alpha" )
      {
         select_data = "AA";
      }
      else if(select_data == "AlphaNumeric" )
      {
         select_data = "AN";
      }
      else if(select_data == "Numeric" )
      {
         select_data = "NC";
      }
      else
      {
        select_data ="";
      }

      $('.disabled').val(input_data + select_data);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selector">
    <div class="get-values">

      <input type="text" value="" class="getvalue">
      <select class="control">
          <option value="">select</option>
          <option value="Binary">Binary</option>
          <option value="Alpha">Alpha</option>
          <option value="AlphaNumeric">AlphaNumeric</option>
          <option value="Numeric">Numeric</option>
      </select>
      <input type="button" value="getcode" class="getcode" onclick="getcodes()">
      <input type="text" value="" class="disabled" disabled>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can change value of options, use it, else - use data api

```js
function getcodes() {
  $('.disabled').val($('.getvalue').val() + $('.control option:selected').data('val'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selector">
  <div class="get-values">

    <input type="text" value="" class="getvalue">
    <select class="control">
          <option value="" data-val="">select</option>
          <option value="Binary" data-val="BY">Binary</option>
          <option value="Alpha" data-val="AA">Alpha</option>
          <option value="AlphaNumeric" data-val="AN">AlphaNumeric</option>
          <option value="Numeric" data-val="NC">Numeric</option>
      </select>
    <input type="button" value="getcode" class="getcode" onclick="getcodes()">
    <input type="text" value="" class="disabled" disabled>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use object. Like this.

```js
var codesArray = {
  "Binary": "BY",
  "Alpha": "AA",
  "AlphaNumeric": "AN",
  "Numeric": "NC"
};

function getcodes() {

  var input_data = $('.getvalue').val();
  var select_data = $('.control').val();

  $('.disabled').val(input_data + codesArray[select_data]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selector">
  <div class="get-values">

    <input type="text" value="" class="getvalue">
    <select class="control">
          <option value="">select</option>
          <option value="Binary">Binary</option>
          <option value="Alpha">Alpha</option>
          <option value="AlphaNumeric">AlphaNumeric</option>
          <option value="Numeric">Numeric</option>
      </select>
    <input type="button" value="getcode" class="getcode" onclick="getcodes()">
    <input type="text" value="" class="disabled" disabled>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think its object not a array

Answer (score 0):

Try with single line if condition

```js
function getcodes() {
  var input_data = $('.getvalue').val();
  var select_data = $('.control').val();
  select_data = select_data == "Binary" ? "BY" : (select_data == "Alpha") ? "AA" : (select_data == "AlphaNumeric") ? "AN" : (select_data == "Numeric") ? "NC" : "";
  $('.disabled').val(input_data + select_data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selector">
  <div class="get-values">

    <input type="text" value="" class="getvalue">
    <select class="control">
          <option value="">select</option>
          <option value="Binary">Binary</option>
          <option value="Alpha">Alpha</option>
          <option value="AlphaNumeric">AlphaNumeric</option>
          <option value="Numeric">Numeric</option>
      </select>
    <input type="button" value="getcode" class="getcode" onclick="getcodes()">
    <input type="text" value="" class="disabled" disabled>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create an `array` for that!

```js
function getcodes()
    {
      
      var input_data  = $('.getvalue').val();
      var select_data_input = $('.control').val();
      var array = ["BY","AA","AN","NC"]; 
      var select_data = array[select_data_input];

      $('.disabled').val(input_data + select_data);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selector">
    <div class="get-values">

      <input type="text" value="" class="getvalue">
      <select class="control">
          <option value="">select</option>
          <option value="0">Binary</option>
          <option value="1">Alpha</option>
          <option value="2">AlphaNumeric</option>
          <option value="3">Numeric</option>
      </select>
      <input type="button" value="getcode" class="getcode" onclick="getcodes()">
      <input type="text" value="" class="disabled" disabled>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this code.

```js
 function getcodes()
    {
      var input_data  = $('.getvalue').val();
      var select_data = $('.control option:selected').data('code');
      (typeof select_data != "undefined") ? $('.disabled').val(input_data + select_data) : "";
    }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selector">
    <div class="get-values">

      <input type="text" value="" class="getvalue">
      <select class="control">
          <option value="">select</option>
          <option value="Binary" data-code="BY">Binary</option>
          <option value="Alpha" data-code="AA">Alpha</option>
          <option value="AlphaNumeric" data-code="AN">AlphaNumeric</option>
          <option value="Numeric" data-code="NC">Numeric</option>
      </select>
      <input type="button" value="getcode" class="getcode" onclick="getcodes()">
      <input type="text" value="" class="disabled" disabled>
    </div>
</div>
```